# Keep Windows File Explorer open

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a CD loaded in my desktop computer with Win10. When I eject it, the File Explorer closes. I would like to remain displayed. How do I do this?

Comment: You could do this until about Win7SP1, then they made it 'smart'. I never found a switch, wish you luck. I used to use the feature for manually copying dozens of SD cards, one at a time… then they made it close the darn window every time - 5 more clicks required for every card :\

Comment: Take a screenshot before dismounting.

Answer (score 0):

Unless things have changed in most recent versions of windows you can't do that. Windows will not allow you to eject a media that is in use, for instance open in explorer. As this is such a common situation Microsoft at some point decided to close the explorer where the cd is open if eject is pressed. Otherwise the eject would have been blocked and that would have confused your grandparent ALOT.

Comment: My grandparents are deceased.